# How to choose which phone should be server and which one should be client?

Tags: ios, swift, networking, p2p, network-framework

I'm developing an app right now, where (I'll keep it to the networking side of things) two devices would transfer data with each other (most likely some JSON data and maybe an image) after putting one phone on top of the other. I've got the device detection logic worked out, but now I'm stuck on the initiation: how would the two phones know which one will first be the client and which one will be the server, and then switch? I'm using Apple's [Network Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network).

Maybe both devices choose a random number, 0 or 1, and then communicate the result with the other device, and the one which has 0 is the server and the one who has 1 is the client? And if they both got the same number start again? I don't have much experience in networking, so I'm really not sure.

PS: I tried using the [MultipeerConnectivity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity) framework, since it offers the peer-to-peer [functionality](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwparameters/3020639-includepeertopeer) I'm looking for, but it isn't being actively supported by Apple (meaning bad for future-proofing) and doesn't offer the customisability I'm looking for, which is why I decided to go a layer down with Network Framework, which is actively supported and easy to interface with.

Comment: Why do you say that multi peer connectivity isn't "actively supported" by Apple?  It is part of the operating system. It isn't deprecated. It is supported.

Comment: True, but it isn't being updated with the latest design paradigms - I mean it's been a while since I've seen anything about MultipeerConnectivity at a WWDC. Didn't mean to make it sound like I'm saying it's basically deprecated, my bad! But Network is objectively more supported than MutlipeerConnectivity by Apple. My guess is they made their own custom branch of the framework for AirDrop, to which they add their new features, but don't add those to the public framework.

Comment: I think you mean that the network framework is being more actively developed, not more supported. This is probably because the multi peer framework came out in iOS 7 while the network framework was first available in iOS 12; you would expect more enhancements to a newer framework as they add features to an initially limited framework.  You should still pick the right framework for the job. Multi peer framework is more abstracted and will work for devices that aren't on the same IP network. Network framework is at a lower level and requires the devices to be on the same IP network.

Comment: You can use the network framework but you will need to implement more functionality yourself.  In answer to your essential question of who should be client and who should be server, I suggest that both devices would be both at all times. The roles only need to be considered during a transaction; the sending device (client) will discover available receiving devices (servers) and make a connection when the the destination is selected.  You then transfer over this session.

Comment: @PrayForTech hi, did you find an answer for this? I'm in the same situation where I want to use NetworkConnection for a device to device peer-to-peer connectivity. I'm new to networking so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

MultipeerConectivity and Network framework have different functions, with **Network** you can communicate creating a Client-Server architecture using TCP/UDP (and Websocket on top of TCP) and WiFi while **MultipeerConectivity** allows you to connect multiple devices through WiFi and Bluetooth. As you can see, they are not the same.

For Network Framework, there is a guide for Custom P2P connectivity made by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/building_a_custom_peer-to-peer_protocol)

I don't know what your app does, but generally one of the devices should be the Server/Listener, for example:

- In a Chat app it would be the one to create the Room
- In a game, it would be the one first to enter the game

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I saw that guide, and watched the keynotes too, it's just that my logic is slightly different. In the Tic-Tac-Toe game, there's always one device browsing and one device listening / hosting (NWBrowser & NWListener respectively). Would there be a way, while still using Network framework, to do both at the same time, maybe on different threads? Since when the user presses "share", the device doesn't know if it should become the client or the server beforehand. I know that's exactly what MultipeerConnectivity is made for, but the framework just doesn't fit everything I need

Comment: If you may receive a connection from any device at any moment, I would use a NWListener alive all the time and receive data there and just create a new connection when I need to connect to a new device. This way, the one sharing is acting as the client and starting the connection, but any device is capable of accepting connections and creating them